# Conditions for an expression to be a perfect square

Tags: quadratics

Find the relation in $a,c$ and $d$ so that

$$(x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d)$$

is perfect square where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: this should have roots $\alpha,\alpha,\beta,\beta$ Try applying properties of a polynomial coefficients after that. hope it helps.

Comment: I tried doing that but couldn't solve those equations to get the condition.

Comment: i got a^2=-2c and 2b^2=-cd. Good enough?

Comment: The answer given in my book is c^2 = a^2d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... never thought of this before.   So let's dig in and see what happens.

But $(x^2+mx+n)^2=$

$x^4+2mx^3 + (2n+m^2)x^2+2mnx+n^2$

So to be a perfect square $a,b,c,d $ must satisfy

$a=2m; $

$b=2n+m^2$ or $b=\pm 2\sqrt {d}+\frac {a^2}4$

$c=2mn $ or $c=\pm a\sqrt {d} $

$d=n^2$ or $d\ge 0$

Comment: Could you please tell that how do you write everything in this mathematical format? I'm new here.

Comment: @Anshuman we use LaTeX.

Comment: When I want to write something formatted, say $\pm\sqrt{d}$ I research what that LaTex code is. Shortcut : I can rightclick on someone else's math code and select "Show math as > TeX command". It shows me the cod for $c=\pm a\sqrt {d}$ is "c=\pm a\sqrt {d}" So I type my code between dollar signs as "\$c=\pm a\sqrt {d}\$"  Some conventions become clear. code for symbols start with backslash, other wise it's just letters. {}will not render but will allow as to "block" more than a single letter into a command.e.g.\$10^{251}\$ is $10^{251}$ but \$10^251\$ only does the first letter $10^251$

Answer (score 2):

If

$$(x^2+px+q)^2=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$

Then
\begin{align*}
2p&=a\\
p^2+2q&=b\\
2pq&=c\\
q^2&=d
\end{align*}
Hence we get two equalities:
\begin{align*}
a\sqrt{d}=c\quad\;\;\text{and}&\quad\;\;\left(\frac a2\right)^2+2\sqrt{d}=b\\
&\text{or}\\
-a\sqrt{d}=c\quad\;\;\text{and}&\quad\;\;\left(\frac a2\right)^2-2\sqrt{d}=b
\end{align*}

Comment: Don't forget q could be negative. So c could equal $-a\sqrt {d} $ and, if so b = the difference, not the sum.